# Run multiple twisted servers?

Tags: python, proxy, twisted, reverse-proxy

Is there some way to run multiple twisted servers simultaneously on the same port? So that they would be listening on different directories (for example: example.com/twisted1 is one twisted script, and example.com/twisted2 is another script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can router your scripts with an web framework, like: Django, Flask, Web2Py...
Or, if you prefer you can create an router script for route manually

Comment: Ok thanks so much, Yeah I'm using Flask. I'll see if it works thanks