# Can I run multiple instances of twisted?

Tags: python, twisted

I would like to know if I can have several instances of 'twistd' process running on the same system (I'm **not** asking about having one twistd instance running and then implement multiple servers as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36877127/run-multiple-twisted-servers) question).

The reason I'm asking this question is that I'm running two separate programs on my server which are both based on twistd and I don't have any idea about their code. What I see from the processes on the servers is that we have two twistd processes running:

```
daemon    1101  0.0  0.4 852756 20828 ?        Sl   Sep06   0:58 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/twistd --uid=1 --gid=1 --logfile=/var/log/twistd.log --pidfile=/var/run/twistd.pid -y /home/myuser/twisted/python/start-it.tac
user2    1132  0.0  2.5 165152 108404 ?       S    Sep06   0:45 /home/user2/user2-env/bin/python /home/user2/user2-env/bin/twistd --umask 0022 --pidfile var/run/user2.pid --logger user2.python.logfile.logger user2
```

I'm not sure if having both of these processes running can interrupt each other and  make any problem or not?

Comment: If they will disturb each other depends on their actual code.

Comment: Yes, it’s fine in general to have multiple unrelated twistd processes running.

Comment: Is it correct to say if they are not listening on the same ports, it should be fine?

Comment: Ports are just one out of an infinite number of possible shared resources.

Comment: Do you know if twistd processes share any other resources?

Comment: Hi Alex it very common to run multiple instance/program using twistd. It will not interrupt each other unless 2 of them using same port to run a server. It is working for me perfect, I am running around 10 to 15 instance on same server, and not get any till now.